# Safari: adblockers detected on webpages

Tags: macos, safari, high-sierra

**Safari** (V13.1.2, High Sierra) often blocks webpages and I do not understand why. Loading a webpages often results in the message

> AdBlocker detected. Please disable your ad blocker to use this page

However, I have no **AdBlocker** installed and there are `No active Content Blockers` in WebSites Preferences but `Javascript` is enabled and `Pop-Up Windows` are allowed.

Any ideas what I can still try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those messages are generated by code on the website you visit, not by Safari.

It’s up to the website author, if they desire to block people from using their website who use adblockers, to write or use appropriate detection code.

Overzealous detection on the part of the website can inadvertently guess that you use an adblocker.

Check your network doesn’t block adverts. Contact the website author to report the bug.

Comment: thx for your message. How can I check my network that it does not block adverts. The strange thing is that in the past I had no troubles with these webpages but now it changed.